# Double time method calling while clicking keyboard done button in android

Tags: android

I have one issue in android application. In my application i am using login page while clicking twice in keyboard done button that login method also calling twice. How to solve this issue..

```
editPassword.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                        && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                            WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
                    if(isValidCredentials()){
                        login();
                    }
                    return true;

                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Here my sample code.. any one can help?...

Answer (score 0):

You can use some kind of guard.

declare a field in your outer class

```
private boolean doubleEnter = false;
...
```

then do somethink like this:

```
editPassword.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
            if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER || keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)
                    && event.getAction() == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                if(doubleEnter){
                getWindow().setSoftInputMode(
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_HIDDEN);
                if(isValidCredentials()){
                    login();
                }
                doubleEnter = false;
                return true;
                }
                doubleEnter = true;
            } else {
                doubleEnter = false;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I think it would be better to use so called keyboard actions: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/text.html#Actions.

In your password editText, add the imeOptions:

```
android:imeOptions="actionDone"
```

And then handle those in your listeners:

```
editPassword.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId, KeyEvent event) {
        boolean handled = false;
        if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE) {
            if(isValidCredential()){
                login();
            }
            handled = true;
        }
        return handled;
    }
});
```